# How to remove a Facebook page's fake likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

There's this company that has a very annoying problem. For some reason their Facebook page started generating *a lot* of likes. The numbers go up to 10K new likes per month.

As these likes all originate from India, it takes no genius to figure out these are all fake likes.

Obviously this is quite an inconvenient situation, because this doesn't really add any value to the company's credibility. Maybe these likes were bought by a competitor to crank up the Facebook advertising costs...

I've searched everywhere, but there doesn't seem to be a solution to somehow programmatically remove the fake likes from the list. I very well understand that there possibly is no way to mass remove all of these likes, so I'm using my last sprinkle of hope to turn to you guys.

Has anyone come across a way to do this? I would love to hear all about the community's ideas about this problem, I can't be the only one suffering from this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps not *quite* what you're after but here's the link to remove/block a fan from your page:

```
http://facebook.com/ajax/pages/fanlist/mutator.php?page_id=[PAGEID]&user_id=[USERID]&act=remove
```

If you could get a list of fan ID's that are fake and your page's ID a simple foreach loop, posting to that URL might do the trick.

Just for clarity, here's a PHP snippet (fill in the blanks yourself):

```
function postToFacebook($friendID){
    ...
    // cURL exec
    ...
}

foreach($friendArr as $curFriend){
    postToFacebook($curFriend);
}
```

This is assuming you have the friend ID's in an array which wouldn't be too difficult to get.

Comment: I didn't know of that URL, thanks. :) Now I only need to find a way to actually get a list of the "latest" likes. It would be ideal if there were a way to check if it's a fake liker... A simple country check for India would probably suffice. Looks like Facebook tries to make this as hard as possible :/

Comment: They're not trying to make anything hard or easy. Merely they're supplying a tool that you can do stuff with. If you feel my answer has answered your question please select the green tick.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm going to try it, but, how do you get the user/friend IDs?